# How can I get around files not being imported when using a listener pattern in python?

Tags: python

I want to create an event-based system where functions can be subscribed to handle certain events.

There are a few ways to do this, I've chosen decorators:

```py
# decorators.py

EVENT_HANDLERS: dict[str, set[Callable]] = defaultdict(set)


def my_event_listener(event_type: str):
    """
    A decorator to subscribe to events with the given event_type.
    """

    def decorator(callback_fn):
        EVENT_HANDLERS[event_type].add(callback_fn)
        return callback_fn

    return decorator

# events.py

def create_event(event: dict):
    for handler_fn in EVENT_HANDLERS[event[event_type]]:
        handler_fn(event)

# handlers.py

@my_event_listener(event_type="test")
def handle_test_event(event):
    logger.info(f"Test event received with payload {event['payload']}")
```

This works great! However I run into problems when `handlers.py` is not imported elsewhere in the codebase. Python only loads files when they're imported somewhere else, and since in this case `handlers.py` has no reason to be imported anywhere it is never loaded, so the decorator never runs, and the callback is never registered.

I don't think this is an issue with the decorator-based approach, as if I were to use a class or whatever I'd have the same problem with imports.

Other than keeping some registry of handlers somewhere, is there a way around this?

Comment: It seems like the function that you call `create_event` is actually intended to handle the events, and you want that code to figure out which registered function to call depending on the event dict's content. So, **that part of the code** is the part that has to know about all of the functions, right? So, why not have **that file** do the imports for `handlers.py` etc.? "Other than keeping some registry of handlers somewhere" - that's what `EVENT_HANDLERS` is.

Comment: Essentially, I can't see how there is a reproducible **problem** here to ask a question about. You know how to import things; if something needs to be imported, then just... do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way around this?

No.

If you're using code to register a thing, the code naturally needs to be run.

You could, for instance,

- keep a list of modules to import, and then `importlib.import_module()` them all, or
- walk the filesystem to find all modules with e.g. a certain name (all `handlers.py`s?) to import, or
- walk the filesystem to find some sort of other metadata to figure out what to import, or
- if you're planning on making your program pluggable, use e.g. [entrypoints](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) mechanism  plugins to register themselves with.